# how can I develop a stochastic gradient descent optimizer for CNNs algorithm in TensorFlow?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I use TensorFlow library in CNNs, python.

I would like to develop a stochastic gradient descent optimizer for CNNs optimizer with the following parameters:

```
learning rate = 0.05,
decay = 1e-6, 
Nesterov momentum 0.9
```

I would like to know how I should change my code to achieve that. Here is the code I have so far:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05).minimize(cost)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished by using the MomentumOptimizer(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MomentumOptimizer) and exponential decay(https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/decaying_the_learning_rate):

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.05
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                       1000, 0.96, staircase=True)

optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, use_nesterov=True).minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)
```

Comment: i use your algorithm but the cost function return nan value. this is my cost function: cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))

Comment: yes it is work with adam but when I use momentum this is my result :

Comment: Iter 88320, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.03125//////
Iter 89600, Minibatch Loss= nan, Training Accuracy= 0.02344

Comment: thanks Thomas when I change the decay value it becomes OK. thanks for your help